# How can I define several turbine types in one wind farm in Floris?

Tags: floris

I did the [exercises](https://floris.readthedocs.io/en/develop/source/examples.html) offered in the Floris documentation. All of them define only one turbine type per wind farm. The JSON configuration file has only one field for "turbine". Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/nrel/floris), it looks like Floris was never intended to allow the definition of a mixed type farm. Is this correct?

I have a small wind park of 5 machines, consisting of 3 different turbine types. Is there any hope to use Floris in this case?

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the JSON input file only allows a single turbine type to be defined. But the individual turbine parameters can be changed after the `Floris` object has been instantiated using the Floris interface.

The following provides an example of how to change the turbine parameters through the list of turbines in the `turbine_map` property of the farm. The rotor diameter and hub height of the 3rd and 4th turbine are changed. Also, an example of how the Cp and Ct curves could be changed for each turbine is shown.

```py
# Initialize the FLORIS interface fi
fi = wfct.floris_utilities.FlorisInterface("example_input.json")

D = fi.floris.farm.turbines[0].rotor_diameter
hh = fi.floris.farm.turbines[0].hub_height

rotor_diameters_new = [D, D, 0.5*D, 0.5*D]
hub_heights_new = [hh, hh, 0.75*hh, 0.75*hh]

# As an example, scaling the Cp and Ct curves by 90%
cp_new = [0.9*x for x in fi.floris.farm.turbines[0].power_thrust_table["power"]]
ct_new = [0.9*x for x in fi.floris.farm.turbines[0].power_thrust_table["thrust"]]

# Assign new parameters to turbines
for i_turb, turbine in enumerate(fi.floris.farm.turbine_map.turbines):
        turbine.rotor_diameter = rotor_diameters_new[i_turb]
        turbine.hub_height = hub_heights_new[i_turb]
        turbine.power_thrust_table["power"] = cp_new
        turbine.power_thrust_table["thrust"] = ct_new
```

After changing the turbine parameters you're interested in, the rest of the FLORIS calculations will use the new turbine types.

Comment: It seems like I should be able to specify `turbine_library_path` in the input file to reference wind turbine yaml files I make